# Trigger http service only after the promise recived in another http service

Tags: angularjs

In my controller I has this two ajax services:

```
    inspectionReviewServices.getValue($scope.object.Id).then(function (result) {
        $scope.inspectionReviews = result.data;
        $scope.inspectionReviewsOriginal = angular.copy(result.data);
    }, function (err) {});



damageEventServices.getValuesByInspReviews($scope.inspectionReviews).then(function (result) {
        $scope.damageEvants = result.data;
    })
```

The http services fired when page is loaded.

The first service is fired `inspectionReviewServices` and second is `damageEventServices`.

The problem is when `damageEventServices` is fired the parameter `$scope.inspectionReviews`

is `undefined` because http services are unsynchronous and promise in `inspectionReviewServices` not received.

So my question how to trigger this `damageEventServices` service only after the promise received in `inspectionReviewServices` ?

Answer (score 2):

```
inspectionReviewServices.getValue($scope.object.Id).then(function (result) {
    $scope.inspectionReviews = result.data;
    $scope.inspectionReviewsOriginal = angular.copy(result.data);
    damageEventServices.getValuesByInspReviews($scope.inspectionReviews).then(function (damageResult) {
        $scope.damageEvants = damageResult.data;
    })
}, function (err) {});
```

Call the dependent in the resolution of the independent.

Answer (score 0):

Chain your promises:

```
promiseReturningService1().then(function(result) {
    //resolved
    promiseReturningService2(result).then(successCallBack, errorCallBack);
    //etc.. etc.. etc...
}, function(error) {
    //rejected
});

//code below this will not wait for the promise executions
alert("hello, I didn't wait!");
```